# Azure App Service renew/change the certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps

I have one question regarding the azure app service certificate update. I have already a certificate bound to one of the azure web apps. But this certificate is going to expire soon. I have renewed my certificate and uploaded a new version of the certificate. So now I have two different certificates in the app service certificate store.

My question is, what is the best way to switch the certificate for the web app without any downtime?

Answer (score -1):

> what is the best way to switch the certificate for the web app without any downtime?

AFAIK, the best way is to turn on automatic renewal of your certificate at any time.

- Choose the certificate from the **App Service Certificates** page.
- Then select **Auto Renew Settings** in the left navigation.
- Select **ON** > **Save**.
- If you have automatic renewal enabled on, certificates will begin renewing 60 days before they expire.

**Renew App Service Certificate automatically**

[image]

Click **Sync** once the renew operation completes which automatically updates the hostname bindings for the ***App Service Certificate*** without causing any ***downtime*** to your applications.

**Refer to the [Renew an expiring certificate of azure app service-SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex,portal#renew-an-expiring-certificate) for more information.**